# Why the ror op in this inline assembly not working properly?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I have written a program to process some data written to disk in big-endian format, so the program needs to swap bytes in order to do anything else. After profiling the code I found that my byte swapping function was taking 30% of the execution time. So I thought to myself, how can I speed this up?
So I decided to write a little piece inline assembly.

I would up replacing this:

```
void swapTwoByte(char* array, int numChunks)
{
    for(int i= (2*numChunks-1); i>=0; i-=2)
    {
        char temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[i-1];
        array[i-1]=temp;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
void swapTwoByte(int16* array, int numChunks)
{
    for(int i= (numChunks-1); i>=0; --i)
    {
        asm("movw %1, %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "rorw %%ax;"
            "movw %%ax, %0;"
            : "=r" ( array[i] )
            : "r" (array[i])
            :"%ax"
        );
    }
}
```

Which does the intended job, but that is a lot of rotate operations.

So here is my question:
According to [this source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate) rorw can take two operands, and in the gas sytax the source operand should be the number of bits to rotate by, but every time I try to replace that list of 8 rotate rights with something like

```
".set rotate, 0x0008"
"rorw rotate, %%ax"
```

I get an assembler error stating:

```
"Error: number of operands mismatch for `ror'"
```

Why is this? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried a simpler optimization such as iterating _forwards_ through the array to be byte-swapped?

Comment: You might want to give bswap a try btw..

Comment: As I understand it iterating forwards can be slower. By stopping at zero I make it easier for look ahead logic to work. At least that is what I have been told.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing? Is the overall thing really slow enough to justify a serious optimization effort? It seems to me like this would be fast enough that what you're really being told is "hey, you aren't really actually doing that much processing"...

Comment: Handling hundreds of gigs of data output by GRETINA. The code takes a 3 hours to execute so I am looking for anything to make it faster.

Comment: Are you really bottlenecked on the performance of bswap or are you overoptimizing it and wasting massive amounts of time on something that will have little to no effect due to memory bandwidth limitations. Use a C expression and spend time more usefully learning to use xperf or another profiler to find what part of the program actually takes the time (real time, not CPU time).

Comment: In the case of gigs of data, overlapping multiple threads (on different disks of course) or overlapping asynchronous I/O would probably gain a lot more performance than trying to do the CPU part faster. A modern CPU can bswap way faster than the memory bandwidth, no matter how bad the code.

Comment: Also, take your fundamental bottleneck as a limiter. If you can read 128MB/sec peak from your hard disk, then no amount of infinite speed bswapping will make any difference in the time it takes to wait around and do nothing while the I/O is in progress.

Comment: Don't profile some unrealistic loop that spins on one buffer. Why benchmark the cache? In real life the memory bandwidth will be the limiter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, use

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
little_endian = ntohs(big_endian);
```

This will compile into optimal code on whatever system you are using, and it will even work if you happen to port your code to a big-endian platform.

However, this will not fix your performance problem because I believe you have misidentified the problem.  Nemo's first rule of micro-optimization:  "Math is fast; memory is slow".

Iterating through a large block of memory and swapping its bytes is extremely cache-unfriendly.  A byte swap is one cycle; a memory read or write is hundreds of cycles unless it hits in the cache.

So *do not swap the bytes until you use them*.  My personal favorite approach is this:

```
class be_uint16_t {
public:
        be_uint16_t() : be_val_(0) {
        }
        be_uint16_t(const uint16_t &val) : be_val_(htons(val)) {
        }
        operator uint16_t() const {
                return ntohs(be_val_);
        }
private:
        uint16_t be_val_;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

This defines a two-byte class that represents a big-endian number in memory.  It implicitly casts to and from uint16_t as needed.  So cast your memory pointer to a `be_uint16 *` and just access it like an array; forget about the byte swapping because the class will do it for you:

```
const be_uint16_t *p = (be_uint16 *)my_block;
unsigned val = p[37];  // or whatever
```

Note that you can even do things like this:

```
be_uint16_t x = 12;
x = x + 1;
write(fd, &x, sizeof(x)); // writes 13 to file in big-endian form
```

The overhead of swapping a value immediately before use is, in my experience, undetectable.  Locality is the name of the game...

Comment: @DeadMG- Thanks.  Lost in the noise, I suspect, but I have been looking for a chance to share my "be_uint16_t" gadget :-)

Comment: I dunno about the gadget, but the "don't swap bytes until you need them makes sense". Toward that end I am rewriting things a little to add the swapping when I actually interpret the data into classes

Answer (score 5):

Consider reorganizing that C++ code a little bit. As written, g++ 4.5.2 compiles it for me as a boring tight loop with four 8-bit `mov`s and two pointer decrements.

```
.L3:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %edx
    movb    %al, -1(%rdi)
    movb    %dl, (%rdi)
    subq    $2, %rdi
    subl    $2, %esi
    jns .L3
```

rewriting it as

```
void swapTwoByte(char* array, int numChunks)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<numChunks*2; i+=2)
        std::swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
}
```

lets the compiler realize what you're doing and turn on the full SIMD power, the core loop now processes 32 bytes at a time:

```
.L4:
    movdqu  (%rdx), %xmm1
    movdqu  (%rax), %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm2, %xmm3
    pshufb  %xmm7, %xmm0
    pshufb  %xmm4, %xmm2
    pshufb  %xmm6, %xmm3
    pshufb  %xmm5, %xmm1
    por %xmm3, %xmm0
    por %xmm2, %xmm1
    incl    %ecx
    movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm2
    punpckhbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqu  %xmm2, (%rdx)
    movdqu  %xmm1, (%rax)
    addq    $32, %rdx
    addq    $32, %rax
    cmpl    %ecx, %r8d
    ja  .L4
```

a `rorw` is not going to beat that.

Comment: tried this, using swap I only got a small improvement in performance, from the swap code taking 28.32% of the time to 26.11%

Answer (score 0):

Swap instructions works with 32bit values. To swap two bytes in word use **xchg  al,ah** instruction.

Comment: Why do this when you could use bswap

Comment: @Mike: agree bswap should be compiled under x86 to "xchg al,ah" instruction.